# html formats two double-row texts horizontally

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to put 2 rows of text, the "API Name" and "Resource Name" to the left, and put another 2 rows of text, the "Service Name" and "Status" to the right.

like this
[image]

However, the result is not what I want. this is my result:
[image]
my code:

```
const ViewHeader = (props: ViewHeaderProps) => {
  const {apiName, resourceName, serviceName, apiStatus, desc, rpcName, verb, uri} = props;
  return (
    <div className="view-api-header">
      <span>
        <div>{apiName}</div>
        <div>{serviceName}</div>
      </span>
      <span>
        <div>{resourceName}</div>
        <div>{apiStatus}</div>
      </span>
      <div>
        <span>{apiName}</span>
        <span>{serviceName}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>{resourceName}</span>
        <span>{apiStatus}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm new to html and react, is there anyway to format the 4 elements correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the HTML code should be like this

```html
<div style="clear: both">
  <div style="float: left">{apiName}</div>
  <div style="float: right">{serviceName}</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both">
  <div style="float: left">{resourceName}</div>
  <div style="float: right">{apiStatus}</divstyle>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! it works. I'll edit the size myself